# How to replace GoogleDialer.apk in Lollipop with AOSP Dialer.apk

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-source

I've made a modified version of Lollipop's AOSP's Dialer.apk and when I run it on an AOSP phone it all works as expected (I've modified the format and content of the notification when there is an incomming call).

I then re-installed the standard Lollipop image onto the phone and replaced /system/priv-app/GoogleDialer/GoogleDialer.apk with the AOSP Dialer.apk (after renaming it as GoogleDialer.apk).

I can launch the app directly to make an outgoing call and it works, however if there is an incoming call the OS is not launching it.

Presumably there is some incompatibility somewhere, any suggestions what or where it might be or how I can get it to work for incomming calls?

Comment: The AOSP app that answers calls is InCallUI.apk, not Dialer.apk.